# How to unregister from an SE site?

Tags: discussion, feature-request

We can today register with any number of SE sites and associate all those site to our profile. All the SE sites to which we are member of, will appear in our Accounts tab under the user profile. But I want to unregister some of the SE sites I have registered with.

How can I do that? More precisely, today do we have any such feature to disassociate from any SE site or can we have such feature made available in SE sites today?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to preserve the account but simply not have it associated with your other accounts, clear all associations from your profile page, then change the OpenID providers of your undesired accounts so that neither of the OpenIDs match any on your desired accounts.

This dissociates your accounts from the rest, and prevents the auto-login mechanism from functioning through the OpenID. You cannot strictly remove an OpenID from an account, so accomplishing this is a matter of displacing your normal OpenID by adding new ones in your profile page.

Outside of that, the only method to truly remove your registration is to [have your account deleted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5999). This will leave all of your posts, but all of the votes from that account will be removed and it will no longer be associated to your other accounts as well.

Comment: Delete account means, I will be deleted from all SE sites at once? For eg:- I am member of English and usage SE site, I want to ONLY delete that account. As mentioned in your answer, If I login and edit my profile to say "delete me", Will it be deleted only from English and Usage site?

Comment: @Sachin You can specify either way when you make the flag. Though I imagine your intent is to only lose the EL&U, so just make sure you're clear in your flag. ♪ Deletion directly only affects one account, but one who wants to can always choose to request that all associated accounts get deleted in one flag, rather than necessarily flagging on every single site.

Comment: Aaah.. that seems fine then. The word "Delete" always gives me shivers since even by mistake if whole account is gone, all your reputation is gone in one shot :)